# Adding a config.ini with pyinstaller

Tags: python

I have a program which looks for a .ini file in the same directory. When I try to use pyinstaller and then run the .exe it says config file not found.

I tried using this command

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>pyinstaller -F --add-data "config.ini;config.ini" vendsend.py
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle), *when you bundle to a single executable (see Bundling to One File), copies of added files are compressed into the executable, and expanded to the `_MEIxxxxxx` temporary folder before execution*.  The file you are looking for should be in the `sys._MEIPASS` folder, as described [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information). Also, keep in mind that such file will be *read-only*.

Comment: So even if I can find the config file, users wouldn't be able to modify it?

Comment: It's *read-only* to the program itself. Read more about [How the One-File Program Works](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works). The config file will be unpacked in a temp folder for the duration of the run, then deleted. Even if a user modifies it, at the next run it will be again unpacked fresh from the distributed .exe file.